# Handle JSON Decode Error when nothing returned

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am parsing json data. I don't have an issue with parsing and I am using `simplejson` module. But some api requests returns empty value. Here is my example:

```
{
"all" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "questions" : [     ]
    }
}
```

This is the segment of my code where I parse the json object:

```
 qByUser = byUsrUrlObj.read()
 qUserData = json.loads(qByUser).decode('utf-8')
 questionSubjs = qUserData["all"]["questions"]
```

As I mentioned for some requests I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "YahooQueryData.py", line 164, in <module>
    qUserData = json.loads(qByUser)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 385, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 420, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

What would be the best way to handle this error?

Comment: Actually, what is your question?

Comment: You answered the questions ;) Looks like I submit the question before really typing the question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, I am glad I helped - it looks now like a telepathy ;) Thanks for including the question, though. Good luck!

Answer (score 229, accepted):

There is a rule in Python programming called "it is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than for Permission" (in short: EAFP). It means that you should catch exceptions instead of checking values for validity.

Thus, try the following:

```
try:
    qByUser = byUsrUrlObj.read()
    qUserData = json.loads(qByUser).decode('utf-8')
    questionSubjs = qUserData["all"]["questions"]
except ValueError:  # includes simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError
    print('Decoding JSON has failed')
```

**EDIT**: Since `simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError` actually inherits from `ValueError` ([proof here](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/v3.0.5/simplejson/decoder.py#L33)), I simplified the catch statement by just using `ValueError`.

Comment: You should always catch the correct exception.  Otherwise you might be missing a bug in the code if there is an actual `ValueError` exception, or some other exception which also inherits from `ValueError`.

Comment: @JulieinAustin: the problem is that in this case you really don't have much choice - stdlib's json module throws ValueError.

Comment: Then I'd stay away from that decoder.  The original question was about the `simplejson` module and it very much does raise `JSONDecodeError` on bad input.  See your earlier link.

Comment: @JulieinAustin: I would do otherwise, since it is actually... standard library. If you are not concerned about speed _too much_, I would use what is already available. Yes, `simplejson` does this in a more fine-grained way, but it has its own issues.

What would you say if the `try...except` block would only encapsulate `json.loads` call? I think this would be better then, but would require some boiler place to meet the requirements (eg. changing class of the exception to something more fine-grained, but lets not try to save the world here).

Comment: `ValueError` is too broad to use in this context. In terms of user code `qUserData["all"]["questions"]` could throw `ValueError` too I believe. Let alone a `ValueError` being raised elsewhere inside `simplejson`. This is the kind of thing that could bite you really hard 6 months down the track when things start breaking for "no reason"

Comment: ValueError would be fine in a `try` block that only surrounded the `json.loads()` call. 
@AnthonyManning-Franklin That would actually be either a `KeyError` (if there is no such `'all'` or `'questions'`) or a `TypeError` if `qUserData['all']` exists but is not a dict

Comment: Touche about the `KeyError` however I would still strongly recommend catching only `simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError`

Comment: `There is a rule in Python programming called "it is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than for Permission" (in short: EAFP). It means that you should catch exceptions instead of checking values for validity` I read this and I had decided to upvote it anyways.

Comment: While it may be more common to apply the idea of "it is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than for Permission" (especially in the python community), note that this approach is *not a general rule*. I am aware that the author did not claim this, but I think it is important to emphasize this for novice developers. There can be situations where you want to stick to the opposite "rule" that is *design by contract* with a strict checking of *pre-conditions*.

Answer (score 45):

If you don't mind importing the `json` module, then the best way to handle it is through `json.JSONDecodeError` (or `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` as they are the same) as using default errors like `ValueError` could catch also other exceptions not necessarily connected to the json decode one.

```py
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError


try:
    qByUser = byUsrUrlObj.read()
    qUserData = json.loads(qByUser).decode('utf-8')
    questionSubjs = qUserData["all"]["questions"]
except JSONDecodeError as e:
    # do whatever you want
```

//EDIT (Oct 2020):

As @Jacob Lee noted in the comment, there could be the basic common `TypeError` raised when the JSON object is not a `str`, `bytes`, or `bytearray`. Your question is about `JSONDecodeError`, but still it is worth mentioning here as a note; to handle also this situation, but differentiate between different issues, the following could be used:

```py
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError


try:
    qByUser = byUsrUrlObj.read()
    qUserData = json.loads(qByUser).decode('utf-8')
    questionSubjs = qUserData["all"]["questions"]
except JSONDecodeError as e:
    # do whatever you want
except TypeError as e:
    # do whatever you want in this case
```

Comment: Unfortunately, json.loads throws a TypeError when the JSON object isn't a str, bytes, or bytearray. This bit me recently because I had thought that JSONDecodeError handled those circumstances, e.g. when the argument to json.loads ends up being None.

Comment: @JacobLee: Thanks. The original question is about the best way to handle the `JSONDecodeError` so I have focused only on that one, but you're right and this case is definitely worth mentioning. I have added it into the answer.

Comment: You can also do `import json` at the beginning and then use `except json.JSONDecodeError as e:` in the exception handling.