# Can you suggest how to handle error such as JSONDecoderError?

Tags: python

Someone asked this before, but the answer is suggesting `print` which is not good.

[Python: Handle JSON Decode Error when nothing returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193/python-handle-json-decode-error-when-nothing-returned)

Given this:

```
class BitbucketError(Exception):
    pass

try:
    response = requests.get('https://bitbucket.org/.......')
    return response.json()['data']

# because JSONDecoderError inherits from ValueError
except (json.JSONDecoderError, ValueError) as e: 
    raise BitbucketError(response.status_code)
```

That's okay. But if I were to use this module in another project, where I do

```
# save to dabase, example 1
raw_code = mymodule.bitbucket.file(...)
db.save(raw_code)

# return json back to user (api server, example 2)
raw_code = mymodule.bitbucket.file(...)
return {'data': raw_code}
```

I am sure I want to catch exception in the snippet above. But the question is, should I just let the original one to propagate or define an exception myself?

I am trying to see how to handle errors properly, since the error could be due to 404, 405, or even 500.

Hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the context of the second piece of code. For example, is it for some internal automation in your application? In that case it might be a good idea to catch exceptions and send an email similar to Djangos error mails (with full stack trace, variables, etc) to someone in your organization that can handle it. If it's for some end user application you probably want to log errors (for example to a mail) AND give the user some kind of feedback. In this case you will want to handle different error codes differently.

Comment: Thanks! Not for autotmation. It's an end-user. Yeah, let's take Django. Before I talk about the front end, we call `bitbucket.find(..)` in our code. In that case, do I just let JSONDecoder propagate or define custom one? I am guessing people feel happier with error all the up to the user application.

Comment: I think this depends a lot of the type of error and what the end user was trying to do. Since I don't have that information I can't answer the question. For example, if the user is trying to add a bitbucket repository name and on lookup you get a 404 from the bitbucket server you need to present a message like "Could not find a repo with that name" to the end user somehow.