# How many exceptions are possible when reading a json in Python/django?

Tags: python, json, django, exception

I have:

```
MY_PATH_DIR = 'path/to/my/json/file.json'

try:
    with open(MY_PATH_DIR, 'r') as f:
        MY_PATH_DIR = json.load(f)
except IOError, RuntimeError, ValueError:
    pass
except PermissionDenied:
    pass
```

And I want to catch all possible errors. With

- `IOError` - I am catching errors when the file doesn't exist or has a
  syntax error (non valid JSON).
- `RuntimeError` - couldn't test it but I think that makes sense from the
  documentation in case of an unexpected error
- `ValueError` - I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193/python-handle-json-decode-error-when-nothing-returned) in case nothing got returned
- `PermissionDenied` - is a specific Django error

Are there any other Exceptions that would make sense?  I'm not sure if `OSError` makes sense here.  I think that would be raised earlier, right?

Comment: I don't think you'll ever see a PermissionDenied error as this code isn't doing anything django specific. And runtime errors should only be caught in very specific cases, when you know you can fix the state of the program. You could write a unit test that checks various inputs for exceptions: file doesn't exist, file is empty, file contains invalid json, file contains non ascii characters. Also, you probably don't want to be overwriting your constant path with the result of the json load.

Comment: This is a bad habit called "pokemon exception handling".  Only catch the exceptions you intend to handle!

Comment: ok, then I will only use the `IOError` one, @BrianSchlenker I tested all the cases you mentioned, they all got caught with `IOError` thanks. And the code is in a django app, hence the `PermissionDenied`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of capturing exceptions is to control the program's behavior when something bad happened, but in an expected way. If you are not even sure what would cause that exception happen, capturing it would only swallow the underlying programming errors you might have.

I wouldn't add as many kinds of exception as possible to that single block of code, you should only add what you care about. To take it to extreme, each line of code would yield certain exceptions but for obvious reason you couldn't do `try except` for all of them.

**Edit:**

For the sake of correctness, since you mentioned `I don't want my code to break` in any case, you could simply do:

```
try:
    # json.load
except Exception as e:
    print "Let's just ignore all exceptions, like this one: %s" % str(e)
```

This is would give you what exception happens as output.

Comment: well, I don't want my code to break just because I am importing a json file, so I care about all possible scenarios that could make it break ?

Comment: ok ok, got it, I will only use the `IOError` then since it's the only one I was able to break it with. I'm not sure however what you mean with >swallow the underlying programming errors . This exception would only raise when I try to import this one specific file, right?

Comment: If you wrap a code block with a certain exception that you don't really know about, then you have a bug in the same code block that would cause the same exception, in this case you will always capture the exception, thinking that it's working, but the bug is never revealed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import sys


def main():
    """Demonstrate the handling of various kinds of exceptions."""
    # This is like what you are doing in your code.
    exceptions = IOError, RuntimeError, ValueError
    try:
        raise random.choice(exceptions)()
    except exceptions as error:
        print('Currently handling:', repr(error))
    # The following is not much different from Shang Wang's answer.
    try:
        raise random.choice(exceptions)()
    except Exception as error:
        print('Currently handling:', repr(error))
    # However, the following code will sometimes not handle the exception.
    exceptions += SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, GeneratorExit
    try:
        raise random.choice(exceptions)()
    except Exception as error:
        print('Currently handling:', repr(error))
    # The code can be slightly altered to take the new errors into account.
    try:
        raise random.choice(exceptions)()
    except BaseException as error:
        print('Currently handling:', repr(error))
    # This does not take into account classes not in the exception hierarchy.
    class Death:
        pass
    try:
        raise Death()
    except BaseException as error:
        print('Currently handling:', repr(error))
    # If your version of Python does not consider raising an exception from an
    # instance of a class not derived from the BaseException class, the way to
    # get around this problem would be with the following code instead.
    try:
        raise Death()
    except:
        error = sys.exc_info()[1]
        print('Currently handling:', repr(error))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```