# Python loop through URL's

Tags: python

I'm attempting take dates from a dataframe and loop through them within URL's. I've managed to print the URL's (1st code), but when I attempt to turn the URL's json into a dataframe (2nd code) I get this response.

> > > AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'

```
#1st code
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('NBADates.csv')
df.to_dict('series')

for row in df.loc[ : ,"Date"]:
    url = url_template.format(row=row)
    print(url)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#2nd code
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

url_template = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom={row}&DateTo={row}&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=Totals&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=SpeedDistance&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

df = pd.read_csv('NBADates.csv')
df.to_dict('series')

for row in df.loc[ : ,"Date"]:
    url = url_template.format(row=row)

    stats = url.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
    headers = url.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']
    stats_df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=headers)

    # Append to the big dataframe
    lineup_df = lineup_df.append(stats_df, ignore_index=True)

lineup_df.to_csv("Stats.csv")
```

Comment: `url` in your code is a string. What is `url.json()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to request the URL. you should send a request and if the response is a json, you should parse it

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I added in the request but now I'm getting this

Comment: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: can you give me a url, with row data fromatted into the string

Comment: https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=10%2F17%2F2017&DateTo=10%2F17%2F2017&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=Totals&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=SpeedDistance&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=

Comment: looks like, sometimes nothing is being returned. check the following link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193/python-handle-json-decode-error-when-nothing-returned

Comment: After printing below the requests call I got <Response [403]>. Does that mean the URL isn't being properly interpreted?

Comment: I figured out there was an issue with the headers that I didn't include in my initial post. You're responses helped me diagnose the issue though so thank you!