# How to get coverage for a unittest inside a for-loop?

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, beautifulsoup, mocking

I'm trying to test an exception with `assertRaises` while patching `BeautifulSoup.select`.

Method that grabs IDs from a web page, takes in a html `resultsPage`

```
def parseOutIds(resultsPage):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resultsPage, "html.parser")

    records = soup.select('some-html-tags')
    parsed = []
    for record in records:
        try:
            ampData = json.loads(record["other-tags"])
            parsed.append(ampData)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError from err # Missing coverage

    return parsed
```

Helper methods and test of above. I'm raising `ValueError` since `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` inherits from it based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381223/12075149).

```
def loadHtml(self, fileName):
    with open('path/to/test'+filename) as f:
         self.html = file.read().strip()

def test_parseOutIds(self):
    self.loadHtml('test-html.html')

    #errorMock method just raises ValueError exception
    bsPatch = patch('bs4.BeautifulSoup.select', self.errorMock) 
    with bsPatch:
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
             parseOutIds(self.html)
```

My current test above is missing coveage for the exception line.

Other points:

1. Do I have to patch json.load as well?
2. From what I've seen from other answers, do I also mock another method to due to there being a loop?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few misconceptions in your code:

- A `ValueError` will not get caught by an `except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` clause - you could catch objects from classes derived from `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`, but not parent classes from `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.
- The `soup.select` call is outside of the `try` block - exceptions thrown from `soup.select` will therefore not get caught anyway.

Now, regarding your testing problem: I would argue that you might not have to patch anything to test `parseOutIds`.  You only have to provide appropriate html input for the respective test case.  In your case, you want to write a test to cover the exception part.  This means, the html input needed will have one of the records to contain invalid JSON data.  This will then cause `json.loads` to throw the `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.