# Read data from a map object within JSON into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access data from a JSON file into a pandas dataframe and seem to be stuck on how to retrieve a data within a map of the JSON.

I want to retrieve the followers_count entity within the user object of this json into a dataframe.

JSON File (sample record) below:

```
{"created_at": "Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017", "id": 892420643555336193, "retweet_count": 12345, "favorite_count": 23456, "user": {"id": 4196983835, "followers_count": 3200889, "friends_count": 104}}
```

here is what I have in terms of code (doesnt work as I dont know how to fetch the followers_count within the user object :

```
        tweet_data_df = pd.read_json('tweet-json.txt', lines=True)
        #Doesnt work
        #tweet_data_df = tweet_data_df[['id', 'favorite_count', 'retweet_count', 'created_at', 'user''followers_count']]
        #works but not enough for me
        tweet_data_df = tweet_data_df[['id', 'favorite_count', 'retweet_count', 'created_at']]
        tweet_data_df.head(5)
```

Appreciate your help !

Comment: Try [json normalize](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html&ved=2ahUKEwia7fe9l6XqAhUY4XMBHcMeCroQFjAAegQIAhAC&usg=AOvVaw2c_NvU8MKZUEGtAjlJ_VAX)

Comment: If json dictionary has a depth = 2 you can use`pd.DataFrame(json_dict).apply(pd.Series)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

If json object (`dictionary`) has a `depth = 2`, (i.e. just 2 nested dictionaries) you can use `.apply(pd.Series)`.

```
{"key": {"key2":{val1, val2}} # depth = 2
{"key": {"key2":{val1, "key3":{val2}} # depth > 2, depth = 3
```

---

```
pd.DataFrame(dic).apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Otherwise `depth > 2` you can iterate through, its keys **recursively**

```
def shrink_depth(dic, output_dict: dict, pkey= None):
    if isinstance(dic, dict):
        for key in dic:
            if key not in output_dict.keys():
                output_dict[key] = []
            
            shrink_depth(dic[key], output_dict, key) # call
    
    elif isinstance(dic, (list, set)):
        for val in dic:
            output_dict[pkey].append(val)
    else:
        output_dict[pkey].append(dic)
```

---

```
# update: Add nested dictionaries to the (id) key
dic = {"created_at": "Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017", "id": 892420643555336193, "retweet_count": 12345, "favorite_count": 23456, 
               "user": {"id": {4196983835: 43424}, "followers_count": 3200889, "friends_count": 104}}

output = {}

shrink_depth(dic, output)

output
```

---

```
{'created_at': ['Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017'],
 'id': [892420643555336193],
 'retweet_count': [12345],
 'favorite_count': [23456],
 'user': [],
 4196983835: [43424],
 'followers_count': [3200889],
 'friends_count': [104]}
```

Comment: Just to understand - are you suggesting that the JSON object be modified to accommodate this ?

Comment: Yeah convert, json to a dictionary, then shrink its depth, but in your case, you can directly use the first one

Comment: sorry, I am stuck converting a txt file with JSON data into a dictionary. Tried some code but that throws an error.

Comment: tried this:

with open('tweet-json.txt', 'r') as json_file: 
    json_dict = json.load(json_file)

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 3974) - it is a valid json file from a third party site though

Comment: Check this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193/handle-json-decode-error-when-nothing-returned

Comment: You may try to modify, your json file content, manually, check if it's valid json format

Comment: it is too big for me to check it manually....tried online formatters with no luck...

Comment: I have no, idea how your file looks like, check this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data, if  doesn't work for you, you may post another question.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without using a dict and flattening the structure ? This doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: poor approach, parse data as string, and use regex to exclude special symbols, then split by `:` and `,` with some logic

Comment: oh, isnt there anything where I could access the elements within the user object using a '.' notation or like ['user']['followers_count'] ?

Comment: `from types import SimpleNamespace`  or define a class with some attributes `self.user = ['user']`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279212/how-to-use-dot-notation-for-dict-in-python