# There was a problem: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a moderator bot that issues a warning for profanity.
I started testing it and it worked, when I exceeded the limit from another account, he banned me. I unbanned that account and reconnected and continued to test other words. After that, the bot began to issue warnings to itself and exceeded the limit, but it cannot block itself.
Now in the console it started to give an error and no warning at all.
I have assumptions that before unbanning, it was necessary to enter an algorithm that resets the counter.
He wrote all the data in json, now he either enters only his id into this file, or enters nothing at all!

Tell me, please, what to do in this situation, maybe there is such an algorithm to reset its counter to zero, or are my assumptions wrong?
Below I will attach the error in the console and part of the code

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in 
_run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mybot\bot\botrun.py", line 54, in on_message
data = json.load(file)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, 
in load
return loads(fp.read(),
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, 
in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in 
decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in 
raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   await bot.process_commands(message)  
   WARN = BADWORDS + LINKS

   for i in  range(0, len(WARN)):
      if WARN[i] in message.content.lower():
      with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
         data = json.load(file)   #line 54
         file.close()

      with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
       if str(message.author.id) not in data:
         data[str(message.author.id)] = {}
         data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] = 1
       else:            
         data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] += 1
         json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

         file.close()
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of that file? The error means that JSON didn't find any data at all.

Comment: Further down you do a `open('users.json', 'w')` which truncates the file. You only write the file on the `else` clause. If you go into the `if`, you end up with an empty file.

Comment: @tdelaney
Yes, it is empty, when a bot is found, it puts {} or its id there, warns

Comment: You suggest removing if and else

Comment: No quite. it raises the error you see. You either need to check for the file size or catch the exception to handle the case.

Comment: In the `if` case, you update `data` but don't save it again. I'm not sure what your code intends. It may be that you should move the `json.dump` out of the else clause so that you always save the data.

Comment: As an aside, the `with` clause closes the file when it exits, you don't need the `file.close()` calls.

Comment: @tdelaney Can you please tell me the best way to write the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle JSON Decode Error when nothing returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193/handle-json-decode-error-when-nothing-returned)

Comment: @MartinZeitler no, I showed one more code below, but it gives a different error in the console