# Python crash course chapter 10 code remember_me wont work as intended

Tags: python

it's code directly from the python crash course 3rd edition book and i can't get it to work properly. it'll work if i run a simpler function and add a username to the file before hand but if the files empty it won't prompt me to enter a new username like it should.

```
from pathlib import Path
import json


def get_stored_username(path):
    if path.exists():
        contents = path.read_text()
        username = json.loads(contents)
        return username

def get_new_username(path):
    path=Path("username.json")
    username = input("What is your username? > ")
    contents = json.dumps(username)
    path.write_text(contents)
    return username

def greet_user():
    path = Path("username.json")
    username = get_stored_username(path)
    if username:
        print(f"Welcome back, {username.title()}!")
    else:
        username = get_new_username(path)
        print(f"We'll remember you when you get back {username.title()}!")
    
greet_user()
```

Comment: The example works as expected. Does not expect a empty file, but something that is a valid json

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please first read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to check carefully, step by step, what happens when the program runs, and see exactly where this differs from your expectation. We don't "find the bug" for you here; we answer questions about a specific part of the code.

Comment: @karl, thankyou ill give it a read ! Im getting jsondecodeerrors "expecting value" when i dont have an existing name in the path file

Comment: Aha. So, the intent is to use the `json` standard library module in order to read the file and make sense of what's in it? Well, yes: an empty file is not valid JSON. It seems like you just want the file to store a single string - why should we need to use JSON for that? But otherwise, you will of course need to check for such an error and handle it. After all, somebody else could create that file, instead of your program, and put any kind of garbage into it.

Comment: As a hint for future questions: if the problem is that an error occurs, the standard here to a) be up front about that; b) try to have a [mre] of the problem; c) show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, as [text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) (format Python exception tracebacks the same way as code, please).

Comment: This should be a duplicate instead. Please see [Handle JSON Decode Error when nothing returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193).

Comment: thankyou for the information and link, just passing the error helped for now. i didn't know the JSON file couldn't be empty, the book did not explain any of that and i tried it word for word from there. it had me very confused. sorry for my messy post!

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC. This program works as intended; if there's no username.json file, it prompts you for a username and then creates the username.json file. If there is a (non-empty) username.json file, then it reads from that file without error. The only way to recreate the error you describe is to create an empty username.json file before running the program, or to go into the username.json file and delete everything in it. How did you end up with an empty username.json file?

Comment: ohhh! your totally right, i deleted the contents of the file so it would prompt me again but i didn't delete the file